# Android date and time picker dialog (spinner style)

Tags: android, datetimepicker

Need a spinner style date and time picker similar to below image.

[image]

Comment: try this https://github.com/florent37/SingleDateAndTimePicker

Comment: need both date picker and time picker in same dialog

Comment: use this its not a drop down but its pick data and time both https://github.com/Kunzisoft/Android-SwitchDateTimePicker

Comment: I have created one similar to the image

Answer (score -1):

You can try any one

https://github.com/drawers/SpinnerDatePicker

https://github.com/RameshBhupathi/PickerView

https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker

or you can use this attributes **datepickermode="spinner"** and **timepickermode="spinner"**